# RecyclerView SpanSizeLookup - HORRIBLE performance with a large data set

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, gridlayoutmanager

The setup - RecyclerView / GridLayoutManager / custom SpanSizeLookup. Nothing unusual, it's just a grid with headers that span the entire width.

However what I've noticed is that performance can severely degrade the more and more items you have in the adapter. I've profiled this and it is 100% because of GetSpanSize in the custom lookup. It's a basic function, but it seems to be called for every item on every frame when scrolling. Sure enough, if I take out my lookup, performance is great regardless of how many items I have. As a use case this could be thousands of items. I start to see performance problems after maybe 1,000 items.

This sounds awfully inefficient from Android's side of things. I've searched high and low for someone else with this problem, but can't seem to find anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

EDIT: Added the code, however this still happens even if I just return 1 instead of doing the actual lookup. This issue seems to be that this is called for EVERY item in the adapter EVERY time the list moves when scrolling.

```
public class SpanSizeLookup : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup
{
    //
    private GridLayoutManager LayoutManager;
    private MyItemAdapter ItemAdapter;
    //

    // SpanSizeLookup
    public SpanSizeLookup( GridLayoutManager layoutManager, MyItemAdapter itemAdapter )
    {
        LayoutManager = layoutManager;
        ItemAdapter = itemAdapter;
    }

    // GetSpanSize
    public override int GetSpanSize( int position )
    {
        switch ( ItemAdapter.GetItemViewType( position ) )
        {
            case TYPE_HEADER:
                return LayoutManager.SpanCount;
            case TYPE_ITEM:
                return 1;
        }

        return -1;
    }
}

// GetItemViewType
public override int GetItemViewType( int position )
{
    if ( ItemList[ position ].GUID.Equals( Guid.Empty ) )
        return TYPE_HEADER;

    return TYPE_ITEM;
}
```

Comment: Please add your code from GetSpanSize so we can help you.  Likely, you are doing something that takes a long time to complete in your code and we can provide a recommendation on how to fix the problem once we see what you're doing.  If you do it right, the adapter should be able to handle thousands of items.

Comment: Well at least you know it's your code that is slowing is down so it's fixable. Just cache span size for items in a map. I have used span size with simple switch / if-else and never faced any issue (and yes, for thousands of items) but I don't understand how list size affects this? RV should only be calling it for items visible on screen. Sounds like issue in your code

Comment: Added the code, thanks. However it is definitely calling GetSpanSize for every Item every time it scrolls, which is why it degrades the more Items you have.

Comment: If I just add a GridLayoutManager.DefaultSpanSizeLookup instead, things work fine. However even if I add a custom lookup which just returns 1, things are STILL slow. This just doesn't make any sense to me, as the default implementation just returns 1 anyway. Any ideas?

Comment: @Sourabh How do u assign the cached span sizes to each position then? Is there a way other than `SpanSizeLookup`? I've just 4 headers at fixed positions in a list containing 2k+ items and still I've to live with all this stutter. Desperately need a way out of this!

Comment: @Petiephant Have u been able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not also overriding GetSpanIndex. The DefaultSpanSizeLookup is essentially this

```
public class DefaultSpanSizeLookup : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup
{
   public int GetSpanSize(int position) 
   {
      return 1;
   }

   public int GetSpanIndex(int position, int spanCount) 
   {
      return position % spanCount;
   }
}
```

If you override GetSpanIndex with the same value, you'll get the same performance as if you used DefaultSpanSizeLookup.